# LINQPad demo database location (DemoDB.sdf)

Tags: linqpad

I"m using LINQPad since a long time. Now I've updated my work stations to version 6 and then i realized i could also use a demo database the same way i do on my home/fun development laptop since an year. But i have no idea how i initially discovered such a database exists at all.

Could anyone point me to simple path or documentation explaining the presence of the demo databases for LINQPad? Probably more LINQPad rookies could be missing such a valuable option.

REMARK: The demo databases are located under C:\Users[current user]\AppData\Roaming\LINQPad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first run LINQPad 6, it extracts the DemoDB.sdf database and creates a connection in the Schema Explorer on the left. The database is based on a Microsoft demo database for SQL Server.

The database requires SQL CE, so when you expand the connection, LINQPad will ask if want to download the NuGet package for SQL CE if not present. The reason for using SQL CE is that it doesn't require installation or configuration, and unlike SQLite, it supports a full range of data types.

Comment: May then the case i have be due to the fact i'm running v5 and v6 side by side? With a couple of connection already existing into the schema explorer in v5 prior to install v6?